# Exoplayer can't play only audio for HLS

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have link only audio https://storage.googleapis.com/as-piepme/1465/livestream/1465.fef238cdc9d9eb0b958d4eb23080e28b/index.m3u8 but Exoplayer can't play above link,
it return "source error". But both IOS and Chrome run fine. My code:

```
SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
player.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(linkPlay)));
player.prepare();
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Update my solution:

```
MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder()
                        .setUri(Uri.parse("https://storage.googleapis.com/as-piepme/1465/livestream/1465.fef238cdc9d9eb0b958d4eb23080e28b/index.m3u8"))
                        .build();
                DefaultHlsExtractorFactory defaultHlsExtractorFactory = new DefaultHlsExtractorFactory(DefaultTsPayloadReaderFactory.FLAG_IGNORE_H264_STREAM, false);
                MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultHlsDataSourceFactory(new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context)))
                        .setExtractorFactory(defaultHlsExtractorFactory)
                        .setAllowChunklessPreparation(true)
                        .createMediaSource(mediaItem);
                player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
```

Comment: Provide logcat details and show your code.

Comment: com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:579)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException: Loading finished before preparation is complete.

Comment: What about your code? Especially the MediaSource one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a Media source.

Try this sample code.

```
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory();
// Create a HLS media source pointing to a playlist uri.
HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource =
    new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
        .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(hlsUri));
// Create a player instance.
SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
// Set the media source to be played.
player.setMediaSource(hlsMediaSource);
// Prepare the player.
player.prepare();
```

For more details check the [documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/hls.html#using-hlsmediasource).

**Update**
Use this one.

```
        DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(this, new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory());
        DefaultTrackSelector.Parameters trackSelectorParameters = trackSelector.buildUponParameters().setMaxAudioChannelCount(0).build();
        trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelectorParameters);
        RenderersFactory renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(this);
        SimpleExoPlayer audioPlayer = = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this, renderersFactory).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build();
        HttpDataSource.Factory factory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("Online Audio Player", DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, true);
        audioPlayer.setMediaSource(new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri("https://storage.googleapis.com/as-piepme/1465/livestream/1465.fef238cdc9d9eb0b958d4eb23080e28b/index.m3u8")));
        audioPlayer.prepare();
        audioPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: I try your code but it not work, I have tested in Exoplayer Demo and it is show the same error. I use ffprobe and see my link has info of video (I dont stream video to link).

Comment: All another my link work fine ( video + audio) but only audio not work. I use library stream audio https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java. My audio link in JWplayer tester play fine. I dont know why.

Comment: thank you for your help. I found solution, ignore H264 when play audio

Comment: Care to explain? The updated code plays an online radio.

Comment: What's the reason for the update?  I'm seeing a similar problem to that of OP, on ExoPlayer v2.14.2 using HlsMediaSource in the same manner as your original answer.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of setMaxAudioChannelCount(0) here?